# How MDIO , SGMII is connected with phy chip and ethernet controller?

Tags: ethernet

I am trying to get a picture like how all these are connected.

My understanding is that

EthernetController ->connects to PhyChip using MDIO

Since, while writing linux drivers I have seen I have used MDIO to talk to phychip. My question is
where is Mac chip? Also, where is SGMMI in the picture? How are they connected? I am looking for a big picture.

Answer (score 1):

There may not be a separate MAC chip as they tend to be integrated into the SOC these days.

SGMII is the link that transfers Ethernet packet data between the MAC and PHY. MDIO is for configuration and status.